# What is 'Content-type: Preventing XSRF in IE' for?

Tags: internet-explorer, csrf, feed, atom-feed

Feeds produced by Google contain a strange comment:

```
<!-- Content-type: Preventing XSRF in IE. -->
```

For example, you can see it near the top of [this](http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/feed/http://img.perezhilton.com/services/rss/atom.xml) feed. Can anyone explain the purpose of that comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems benhoyt on hacker news [asked and answered this question](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=29386).

> I've just been tightening up our upcoming microPledge website -- http://micropledge.com -- to prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF). I added a random SHA as a form key to each form.
>   But! Then I discovered this lovely IE security hole. An attacker can use cross-domain JavaScript and an mhtml: redirect to grab the page, get the form key, and then do the POST. Brilliant! Anyone have any experience in getting around this?

...

> IE parses the first part of an MHTML document as HTTP-style headers, so if you have an HTML comment at the start of your pages with "Content-Type: Something crazy" followed by a blank line, that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

XSRF (sometimes CSRF) is Cross-site Request Forgery: [read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)